# how to reset the npm configuration?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, npm-install

I missed up my npm after running `npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7` command. now when I try to install a package to my repository I get the following error

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "node6.10.2", you can set the PYTHON env variable
```

How can I reset my npm? I tried removing it using the following command

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
```

and then downloaded node.js from their [official website](http://nodejs.org) but it didn't resolve the error

Answer (score 2):

Try `npm config delete config_name`
This is for delete npm config.
Or you can  `npm config set config_name=default_value`
If you wanna set to default value.
All your npm config can be view in .npmrc file.

Comment: I upvoted you as your answer helped me research the solution that helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by running `npm config edit` command and removed the first line below:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

that was saying `python=/path/to/executable/python2.7`

hope It helps